# Queue with multi-field sorting on priority and time

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

## Intent

Implement a task queue with sorting based on 1) priority and 2) time, specifically, time at which task was created or time-stamped (not inserted in the queue), giving preference to tasks with older time stamps.

[image]

#### Tried

This is what I got so far; much simpler than I thought having assumed it would require more than just a single `PriorityQueue`. In the comparator, if two priorities are equal, another comparison is made on `Task.time`, otherwise, comparison is based on just `Task.priority`.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class QueueWithPriorityAndTimeSort {
   enum TaskPriority {
      High, Medium, Low
   }

   class Task implements Comparable<Task> {   
      long time;
      TaskPriority priority;

      Task(TaskPriority p, long t) {      
         time = t;
         priority = p;
      }

      public int compareTo(Task task2) {
         return priority.compareTo(task2.priority);
      }
   }

   class HighPriorityWithTimeComparator implements Comparator<Task> {
      public int compare(Task task1, Task task2) {
         int compareResult = task1.compareTo(task2);
         if( compareResult == 0){           
            //same priority, now compare on time
            if( task2.time < task1.time)
               compareResult = 1;
            else 
               compareResult = -1;
         }                          
         return compareResult;
      }
   }

   public void buildAndTestQueue(){
      PriorityQueue<Task> queue = 
            new PriorityQueue<Task>(3, new HighPriorityWithTimeComparator());
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.High, 9));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.Low, 7));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.Low, 3));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.High, 2));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.Medium, 5));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.Medium, 4));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.High, 6));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.High, 8));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.Low, 15));
      queue.add(new Task(TaskPriority.Low, 10));

      Task m = null;
      while ((m = queue.poll()) != null)
         System.out.println(
            String.format("Priority: %s, %d", m.priority, m.time));     
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      QueueWithPriorityAndTimeSort queueTest = 
         new QueueWithPriorityAndTimeSort();
      queueTest.buildAndTestQueue();
   }
}
```

#### Question

Is this a valid approach? I don't believe the added comparator logic changes the time complexity; aside from that, I don't see any glaring issues.

Comment: Yes, it's the correct approach. You could use `Long.compare()` to compare your times. And you could transform your main method into a proper unit test to check that everything works as expected.

Comment: sure, this is a valid approach. the only thing that seems a bit weird to me is how the comparison logic is split across the compareTo implementation in Task and an external Comparator. why not just put all of the comparison logic into one or the other? it's been a while since I used PriorityQueue, but iirc the PQ will just work (i.e. without being supplied a Comparator) if your value type implements Comparable.

Comment: I am curious as to why are you using a Comparable and Comparator when you can implement all the logic inside the Comparator?

Comment: @wdf thought about myself and decided to split the logic based on context and use. Comparison based on priority and time is relevant only when `Task`s reside in a queue, otherwise, time isn't that important. Separating these concerns allows sorting based on specific needs for increased flexibility.

Comment: @raffian That seems to be an overkill. But since your objective is to have a flexible sorting algorithm, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer will address the following comment that you made :

> Separating these concerns allows sorting based on specific needs for
>   increased flexibility

There are better ways to separate the concerns and make your code even more flexible such that you can change the sorting strategy without changing your code. Sounds exciting?

Let's start by defining a Comparator just for comparaing priorities :

```
class HighPriorityComparator implements Comparator<Task> {
        public int compare(Task task1, Task task2) {
            return task1.priority.compareTo(task2.priority);
        }
    }
```

Let's define a Comparator just for comparing time :

```
class TimeComparator implements Comparator<Task> {
        public int compare(Task task1, Task task2) {
            int compareResult = 0;
            if (task2.time < task1.time)
                compareResult = 1;
            else
                compareResult = -1;

            return compareResult;
        }
    }
```

Now for the best part. Let's define a Comparator that will allow you to mix and match comparison logic.

```
class MixAndMatchComparator implements Comparator<Task> {

        List<Comparator<Task>> comparators;

        public MixAndMatchComparator(List<Comparator<Task>> comparators) {
            this.comparators=comparators;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
            int compareResult = 0;
            for(Comparator<Task> comparator : comparators) {
                if(comparator.compare(o1, o2)!=0) {
                    return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
                }
            }
            return compareResult;
        }

    }
```

Now let's sort on priority and if priority is equal, then sort on time :

```
List<Comparator<Task>> comparators = new ArrayList<Comparator<Task>>();
//first sort on priority            
comparators.add(new HighPriorityComparator());
//then on time
comparators.add(new TimeComparator());
MixAndMatchComparator orComparator = new MixAndMatchComparator(comparators);
PriorityQueue<Task> queue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(3, orComparator);
```

Wait! You changed your mind? You now want to sort on time and if time is equal, then on priority? Just change the order in which you add the comprators to the list :

```
List<Comparator<Task>> comparators = new ArrayList<Comparator<Task>>();
//first sort on time    
comparators.add(new TimeComparator());
//then on priority
comparators.add(new HighPriorityComparator());
MixAndMatchComparator orComparator = new MixAndMatchComparator(comparators);
PriorityQueue<Task> queue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(3, orComparator);
```

Comment: interesting, I like it...and yes, I am excited :-D, btw, there's a bug in `TimeComparator`, if two times are equal, the result will not return 0.

Comment: @raffian I assumed that's what you wanted? All I have done is moved your code to different classes. The bug was already present in your code :). I suggest you accept my answer because it won't get any better than this! :)

Comment: Unless you take responsibility for that bug, I ain't accepting squat :-D, j/k,